# Turtle in python, do not want line to print

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am writing this code to print polygons. If the number is two or less, it is supposed to print nothing according to my professor but I cant figure this out. Can somebody tell me what I need to write in my function for 2 or less side numbers to not print anything?

```
import turtle
import math
turtle.shape("turtle")
turtle.speed(3)
from turtle import *
pensize (5)
pencolor ("purple")

def polygon(num_side, length):
    for i in range(num_side):
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(360/num_side)

print(polygon(2, 100)) #nothing?
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(50, 0)
turtle.pendown()
print(polygon(3,100)) #triangle
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(50, 0)
turtle.pendown()
print(polygon(4, 100)) #square  
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(50, 0)
turtle.pendown()
print(polygon(5, 100)) #pentagon
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(50, 0)
turtle.pendown()
print(polygon(6, 100)) #hexagon
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(50, 0)
turtle.pendown()
print(polygon(7, 100)) #heptagon
```

Comment: You are just printing `None` every time since `polygon` doesn't explicitly return anything.

Comment: it prints a line and the rest print the correct shapes im looking for but the line is supposed to not print because it is a line and not a polygon

Comment: When you say "print", do you mean draw on the window?

Comment: Yes. it draws a line along with the other shapes when it shouldnt be drawing anything (apparently)

Comment: Well, in that case sabbhahillel's answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exit if the number of sides is less than three and only output if n is more than 2. Thus, the if will take care of this.

```
import turtle
import math
turtle.shape("turtle")
turtle.speed(3)
turtle.pensize (5)
turtle.pencolor ("purple")

def polygon(num_side, length):
    if num_side > 2:
        for i in range(num_side):
            turtle.forward(length)
            turtle.left(360/num_side)

turtle.pendown()
for n in range(10):
    polygon(n, 100)
```